# Unusual behavior : recyclerview doesn't show items of some subcategories

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have three fragments :

- fragment A: gridlist of categories
- fragment B: show items of pressed category
- fragment C: shows detail of selected items

It all works well, or so I thought until I started clicking randomly on categories so that I can go from A to Bo, B to C and then from C to B to A. it works for the first 10 clicks until it stops randomly and doesn't show the items of pressed category meaning fragment B doesn't show anything but the bottomNavigationView . When I click on the back button on the emulator , fragment A doesn't show either. Just both blank and show the bottom and top navigationbars.
Weird thing is the logs show that the adapters have fetched the data, my lists are also populated .
Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**

Made an edit to add some code since I checked my logs ( getting the data correctly) and the layout inspector (I didn't see anything out of the ordinary).
here's my navigation graph :

```
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/homePageFragment"
    android:name="beatview.android.huruapp.activities.homepage.HomePageFragment"
    android:label="home_page_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/home_page_fragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_homePageFragment_to_professionDetailsFragment"

        app:destination="@id/professionDetailsFragment">
        <argument
            android:name="category"
            app:argType="string" />
    </action>
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_homePageFragment_to_favoritesFragment"
        app:destination="@id/favoritesFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_homePageFragment_self"
        app:popUpTo="@id/homePageFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/professionDetailsFragment"
    android:name="beatview.android.huruapp.activities.homepage.professions.ProfessionDetailsFragment"
    android:label="profession_details_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/profession_details_fragment">
<argument
    android:name="category"
    app:argType="string"
    android:defaultValue="null" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_professionDetailsFragment_to_startInterviewFragment"
        app:destination="@id/startInterviewFragment" >
        <argument
            android:name="interviewName"
            app:argType="string" />
        <argument
            android:name="interviewCat"
            app:argType="string" />
    </action>
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_professionDetailsFragment_pop_including_homePageFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/homePageFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/startInterviewFragment"
    android:name="beatview.android.huruapp.activities.homepage.interviews.StartInterviewFragment"
    android:label="start_interview_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/start_interview_fragment" >

    <argument
        android:name="interviewName"
        app:argType="string"
        android:defaultValue="null" />
    <argument
        android:name="interviewCat"
        app:argType="string"
        android:defaultValue="null" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_startInterviewFragment_pop_including_professionDetailsFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/professionDetailsFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

</fragment>
```

and my fragments( they all look the same ):

```
 override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    viewModel=ViewModelProvider(this, HomePageModelFactory(HomePageRepository())).get(
       HomePageViewModel::class.java)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.home_page_fragment, container, false)
    binding.recyclerProf.layoutManager= GridLayoutManager(requireContext(),2)
    val itemDecoration = GridSpacingItemDecoration(2,5,false )
    binding.recyclerProf.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration)
    adapter= HomePageAdapter(this.requireContext())
    viewModel.getName()
    Thread.sleep(300)
    viewModel.setupData()
    //to ensure the two way binding
    binding.myViewModel = viewModel

    //to make it sole owner of this lifecycle
  binding.recyclerProf.adapter=adapter
  return binding.root
}
fun shouldInterceptBackPress() = true
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    viewModel.setupData()
    viewModel.getName()
    viewModel.listCategory.observe(this,{
        adapter.setListData(it)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })

    binding.recyclerProf.adapter=adapter
    gotoFaves()
  getUserFull()
    binding.greetings.setText("Hello, "+liveUserSettings.value)
}
```

and my adapters ( they also have the same structure):

```
fun setListData(data: List<InterviewCategoryDB>) {
    this.categories = data.toMutableList()
    Log.i("mycategories",data.size.toString())
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MainViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val binding = CardItemsBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
    return MainViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {

   return  categories.size


}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainViewHolder, position: Int) {
    Log.i("myAdapterSizebind", position.toString())
    val category = categories[holder.adapterPosition]
    // bind ui 
    //onlicklistener for item
 

    holder.binding.motherCard.setOnClickListener {
            val action = 
HomePageFragmentDirections.actionHomePageFragmentToProfessionDetailsFragment(category.interviewCategoryName)
            findNavController(holder.itemView).navigate(action)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check your logs, add debug logs and check layout boundaries.Then, if there was a problem, add your code and screenshot to this question.